# How to perform this Gaussian-like integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Prove:

$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2 x}\right)=1,
$$

where $\mu>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: substitute $x=1/y^2$, then use [Glasser's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem#A_special_case:_the_Cauchy%E2%80%93Schl%C3%B6milch_transformation). See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution).

Comment: This solves the problem. Thank you so much!